# How to distribute razor views to another application in .NET Core

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, view, asp.net-core-middleware

I have created web application - `Asp.Net MVC` in `.NET Core`.

This application contains some `Razor Views` but I would like to share these views to another application like for example with DLL or like middleware.

Here is some information about example with distribution `Controllers` but around `Views` nothing special - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/app-parts

I've tried add Controller like this:

```
var assembly = typeof(Project.HomeController).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

services.AddMvc()
        .AddApplicationPart(assembly);
```

This works very well, but I don't know how add the Views.

How can I distribute the `Razor Views` to another application? Is it way import them like a middleware to the `MVC middleware`?

Comment: First question is, why would you want do this? Distribute views w/o their controllers. And if you also distribute controllers, why not putting controllers and views in the same assembly? A view is always pretty specific to a controller, so reusing a view has little value w/o the backing controller for it. Also distributing views as assembly will prevent the consumers from customizing the templates (adding or removing certain information etc)

Comment: I would like reuse the part of application with specific graphic design which is everything same. The view is in same Assembly like controllers but I don't know how view add to another application in Startup. Can you put some sample how Views with controllers connect with specific application?

Comment: @Tseng I've updated my question, how I add the controller and this works very well but I don't know how I can I add the views. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a normal netstandard1.6 library-i.e., where your controllers are, and embed the view resources into that dll in your csproj using the following:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Views\**\*.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

After that, you can then register these using the RazorViewEngineOptions:

```
// Add views provided in this assembly.     
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
{
    options.FileProviders.Add(
        new EmbeddedFileProvider(typeof(ClassInLibrary).GetTypeInfo().Assembly));
});
```

Where "ClassInLibrary" is a class in your library that you can then get the assembly information from.

Comment: I've tried these steps but in this line: `new EmbeddedFileProvider(typeof(ClassInLibrary).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)); `- I get error "ClassInLibrary" this is only a namespace - and if I tried listed items of these namespace I only got the Controllers classes, how can I fix this?

Comment: @Jenan Like I explained, the ClassInLibrary is a type i made up. This could be any class that is in the library that you are createing-e.g., one of your controllers

Comment: OK, I see now. :)